# What are the class quests?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

It tells me whenever I select a new character how many "Class Quests" I've done.  Those appear to be different from normal quests, as I know I'm done many as an Archer, and it says I've done "0 of 5" class quests.

I don't see it explain what those are anywhere.  What are those quests?

Comment: They're checkpoints in reputation. Reputation is gained through various actions, including leveling, completing quests, and killing gods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Tooltip of your Character, it tells you what your current Classquest is, e.g. while logging in.

See this screenshot:

[image]

It is meant as some sort of progress through the game and you can also get an achievement on Steam for doing a lot of them.

Comment: Oh *that's* the class quest?! They could've made that more obvious.